# which one is a better solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

**Solution 1:**

```
Dim i As Integer = CInt(_table.Rows(0).Item(3))
Do While i - 2 > 0
                _tableBackLogs.Merge(Global.DataAccess.GetDataTable("SELECT SubjectID,SubjectName,Grade FROM SubjectPI WHERE RegNo='" & CInt(HttpContext.Current.Session("userName")) & "' AND Status='Fail' AND Semester='" & i - 2 & "'"))
                i = i - 2
            Loop
```

**Solutin 2:**

```
 If i = 1 Then
                Global.DataAccess.GetDataTable("SELECT SubjectID,SubjectName,Grade FROM SubjectPI WHERE RegNo='" & CInt(HttpContext.Current.Session("userName")) & "' AND Status='Fail' AND Semester='" & i & "'")
            ElseIf i = 2 Then
                Global.DataAccess.GetDataTable("SELECT SubjectID,SubjectName,Grade FROM SubjectPI WHERE RegNo='" & CInt(HttpContext.Current.Session("userName")) & "' AND Status='Fail' AND Semester='" & i - 2 & "'")
            ElseIf i = 3 Then
                Global.DataAccess.GetDataTable("SELECT SubjectID,SubjectName,Grade FROM SubjectPI WHERE RegNo='" & CInt(HttpContext.Current.Session("userName")) & "' AND Status='Fail' AND Semester='" & i - 2 & "'")
                'On and on....upto i=8
            End If
```

Which one is a better solution in terms of performance and speed of execution??

**UPDATE:** I am storing the data into a DATATABLE....and then using it with a ListView.

Comment: Global.DataAccess.`GetDataTable` is a function which returns a `DataTable`

Comment: The two solutions are not comparable. In the first one you get an imprecised amount of records and merge them repetitively together (more than one semester). In the second you get only the records for a specified semester (but that i values are a bit strange). By the way, it's not related to the question, but that code is subject to Sql Injection

Comment: @Steve OKay thanks ...but if the second solution was something like this  ` `Global.DataAccess.GetDataTable("SELECT SubjectID,SubjectName,Grade FROM SubjectPI WHERE RegNo='" & CInt(HttpContext.Current.Session("userName")) & "' AND Status='Fail' AND (Semester=1 OR Semester=2 OR Semester=3")`
`  Here i am trying to get the data of three semesters together...the sql command may be wrong but i hope you get what am trying to explain...what about this solution??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Which one is a better solution in terms of performance and speed of execution??
```

Well, putting aside the concern about string concatenation, the best approach will be to get all the data needed in the minimum number of calls to the database.

You should change your code to identify which semesters are needed and then put everything together in an unique query.
So, as you said, in your comment, `(Semester=1 OR Semester=2 OR Semester=3")` would be better.

From your code, I assume that `semester` is a varchar field. That's bad because, if it was a number, you could write a better query using minimum and maximum values. (Also if you can assure that semesters are in consecutive order.). `(Semester >= 1 AND Semester <= 3)`

However, the best performance you can get out of this, is if in your datatable has the correct indexes.

Comment: Hey Steve...sorry for the late reply..`semester` is a `Integer` field..i am doing it with using the `do while` loop because if in future i have have to change something...i'll have to change a lot of statements with the `IF END IF` path..well i agree `the best approach will be to get all the data needed in the minimum number of calls to the database` am accepting yours as answer.

Answer (score 2):

Is there some reason not to use "IN" to grab all these semester numbers in one query, as in something like this?

```
Global.DataAccess.GetDataTable("SELECT SubjectID,SubjectName,Grade 
    FROM SubjectPI 
    WHERE RegNo='" & CInt(HttpContext.Current.Session("userName")) & 
           "' AND Status='Fail' 
              AND Semester IN ('8', '6', '4', '2'))");
```

Because if you *can* use "IN", do. "Don't Repeat Yourself," yeah sure, ya betcha.

Comment: because the value of `i` is not fixed...`i` changes with different conditions.

Comment: That doesn't stop you from using "IN." You're already building up your query out of substrings. Make a function that generates the correct string for the "IN," and use that as part of your query-building.

Answer (score 1):

One principle of writing software is: Dont Repeat Yourself (DRY). So solution 1 is definitely better. You will run into code maintenance problems otherwise. I doubt you will get any measurable speed difference between the two solutions.